# google GetDirection in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-mobile

- I have used this following code for getting route for two directions but i need to implement multiple destination options in android like GetDirections.
- Even i tried the method of drawline() functionality also but it will not show the route instructions like (turn left,right, etc.,).
- please  can any one help me for code the route path or to embed the feature of  waypoints listed link below

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

**Code**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=st.%20louis,mo&daddr=washington,dc%20to:chicago,il%20to:new%20york,ny");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: In Android API you should execute Directions API web service request and draw polylines based on the response. You can use Java client for web services to make your life easier: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java. The example of implementation can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47556917/5140781