# Android connecting Heatmaps to current location

Tags: android, google-maps, heatmap

I was trying to plot a heatmap on Android device using "Google Map" with the help of tutorial as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/heatmap) on Google developers, using [Android utility library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/)

Using the sample code as described in the tutorial, I implemented the heatmap as below:

[image]

As you can see, the heat map locations are displayed in Green circles and dots, but actually, I wanted to achieve something like below:

[image]

That is connecting the heat map via a line to the current location.

Any idea or help?

Comment: did you get the dot lat lng?

Comment: yes, and I am passing the list of LatLng to heatmap builder

Comment: try to pass these lat & lng to draw a poly line with color red

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, btw any example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425499/how-to-draw-interactive-polyline-on-route-google-maps-v2-android
try this

Comment: this is polyline with color red try to draw poly line according to lat lng

Comment: @WaleedAsim thanks for the guidance, I will try to implement it

Comment: Sure and happy coding :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492459/android-google-maps-draw-a-route-between-two-points-along-the-road its another tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SphericalUtil.interpolate()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#interpolate-LatLng-LatLng-double-) from [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/) to get additional points between your source points and sent it to `HeatmapTileProvider` to get "heat map line". For example, with this code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    // Create the gradient.
    int[] colors = {
            Color.rgb(102, 225, 0), // green
            Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)    // red
    };

    float[] startPoints = {
            0.2f, 1f
    };

    Gradient gradient = new Gradient(colors, startPoints);

    final List<LatLng> sourcePolyPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    sourcePolyPoints.add(new LatLng(28.537266, 77.208099));
    sourcePolyPoints.add(new LatLng(28.536965, 77.209571));
    sourcePolyPoints.add(new LatLng(28.536786, 77.209989));
    sourcePolyPoints.add(new LatLng(28.537886, 77.210205));
    sourcePolyPoints.add(new LatLng(28.537886, 77.210205));

    final List<LatLng> interpolatedPolyPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int ixPoint = 0; ixPoint < sourcePolyPoints.size() - 1; ixPoint++) {
        int nInterpolated = 50;
        for (int ixInterpolated = 0; ixInterpolated < nInterpolated; ixInterpolated++) {
            LatLng interpolatedPoint = SphericalUtil.interpolate(sourcePolyPoints.get(ixPoint),
                    sourcePolyPoints.get(ixPoint + 1), (double) ixInterpolated / (double) nInterpolated);
            interpolatedPolyPoints.add(interpolatedPoint);
        }
    }

    // Create the tile provider.
    mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
            .data(interpolatedPolyPoints)
            .gradient(gradient)
            .build();

    // Add the tile overlay to the map.
    mOverlay = mGoogleMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(28.536965, 77.209571), 16));
}
```

you get smooth "heatmap line" between your source points, like that:

[image: Heat map Path]

You can adjust color and width of "heatmap line" by `HeatmapTileProvider` parameters. And if you need polyline only on road you can use [Snap to Road](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) part of [Google Maps Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro) or examples provided in [Waleed Asim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6211906/waleed-asim) comments.