# How to implement Google maps draw route with primefaces gMap

Tags: java, google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I implemented gMap from https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/geocode.xhtml and it's working as expected but I have a requirement to draw the route from user location to a point on map.

I see that they (primefaces) have polylines https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/polylines.xhtml but I'm not sure if I should use that because it's probably not gonna be a good route, because it will ignore buildings and things like that between the 2 points right?.

Where can I find a guide or example to implement this requirement properly with primefaces usage?

Comment: Guys, in my search the best I have found to accomplish my requeriment is the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492459/how-do-i-draw-a-route-along-an-existing-road-between-two-points what do you think? (see best answer there)

Comment: I manage to adapt the above code to primefaces library components, I will post code later today for posteriority