# Android Google Maps path between 2 markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to run the following example to display route directions between two locations on Google Map.

https://www.wingsquare.com/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android/

However, I keep getting the following error in Android Studio run tab when I click on the map to create two markers:

DownloadTask : {   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",   "routes" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}

Also, a toast message shows "No route found".

I have the following APIs enabled in Google Developers Console:

- Maps SDK for Android
- Directions API
- Distance Matrix API
- Geocoding API
- Maps Embed API
- Maps JavaScript API
- Places API

However, the error message doesn't seem to have changed between enabling each of the APIs.

Comment: Did you create your own API key and update the google_maps_api.xml file?  The example does not include an API key.  Note you can test the URL (with API key) in a web browser to eliminate the app from the investigation.

Comment: This can help you, [How do I draw a route, along an existing road, between two points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492459/how-do-i-draw-a-route-along-an-existing-road-between-two-points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once i face the same problem. Then i check the google account for map sdk. There i found that my account was not added with some payment options. Direction API requires payment method. And finally check that you put correct api key in google_maps_api.xml

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem, just ensure that you have enabled the directions api. You need both the sdk for android/ios and the directions api enabled to get it to work.